# Best practice when using operator[] in c++

Tags: c++

I have a myClass that uses the operator[] to access some data. And this class us created like this:

```
shared_ptr<myClass> ptr (new MyClass);
```

So when i want to use the operator[] I can do it like this two ways:

```
ptr->operator[]("something");  // 1
(*(ptr.get()))["something"];   // 2
```

What is the best way to go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither:

```
(*ptr)["something"];
```

`ptr.get()` is for when you need the pointer value, `operator->` is for accessing members, and `operator*` is for when you need a reference. In this case the reference is the most convenient because of the need to spell out the name of `operator[]` when using `->`.